# Abrir teclado mobile automaticamente

Tags: javascript, teclado

Atualmente eu tenho o seguinte bloco atrelado a ação do usuário.

`$(".class-botao").focus()`

Quando o usuário interage com a pagina o teclado mobile é exibido normalmente.

Porém em minha aplicação existe um método que verifica se existe algum input vazio ao carregar a pagina e se existir eu dou um `.focus()` no elemento;

```
autoFocus: function(scope) {
    var firstInput = $('.class-input.empty:required').filter(':first:visible');

    if (!firstInput.length) {
        return false;
    }

    firstInput.focus();
    return true;
},
```

Tudo funciona normalmente mas o teclado não aparece (IOS/Android),

Ja tentei simular eventos `.trigger('click // touchstart')` logo depois do `focus()`, mas nada do teclado aparecer :/

Alguém tem alguma dica ?

Comment: *"Porém em minha aplicação existe um método que verifica se existe algum input vázio ao carregar a pagina"*, esse método é seu? Se sim, coloque-o na pergunta e alguém poderá te ajudar

Comment: Editado amigo, brigadão pela dica :)

Comment: Coloca tbm o html e css relevante para a verficação da funcionalidade. Lendo sua função me parece que está ok, mas você tem certeza de que o firstInput está recebendo somente um elemento e não uma coleção contendo apenas um item?

Answer (score 2):

O teclado virtual de dispositivos móveis **só pode ser ativado por ações do usuário**, por definições de usabilidade.

Dessa forma, o método correto para invocar o teclado dos dispositivos móveis é por meio do tipo do elemento input, por exemplo:

`<input type="text" />` invocará automaticamente o teclado padrão alfanumérico ao receber foco, enquanto
`<input type="number" />` invocará o teclado numérico

Há duas exceções para javascript:

- Alguns dizem que o método global `prompt()` funciona
- Disparar o evento `focus` dentro de eventos levantados por ação do usuário, por exemplo: `click`, `mousedown`, ou `mouseup`